# When sending mailing incorrect amount of contacts displayed

Tags: civimail

I have a mailing list group called "All Contacts". It has about 450 contacts with valid email addresses that we would like to send email to.

When we go to "New Mailing" and select All Contacts it only sends to 270 contacts.  I am wondering Why it is not sending to all of the contacts?   Only about 7 contacts are opted-out so it should be sending to at least about 350 contacts.

*After further review, it appears as though it is contacts that have been recently imported that are not being added to the Mailing recipients list.  Event though they have been added to the mailing list group.

THanks,

Comment: Do you mean count of contacts, not amount?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem, probably with version 4.3, and found that a recent import had resulted in contacts with "deceased" set to null, while the query that selected e-mail addresses for a mailing excluded contacts where "deceased" was not false, thus excluding all those newly imported contacts with "deceased" set to null.

I re-imported those contacts, explicitly setting "deceased" as False, and then I was able to send e-mail to them.

Comment: Thanks galgeek!  Here that fixed it for me.  Really appreciate it.  What I did was run this command in phpMyAdmin.  UPDATE `civicrm_contact` SET `is_deceased`= '0' WHERE `is_deceased` IS Null

Comment: can you please file an issue for this and if you can also a patch for the code (CRM/Mailing/BAO/Mailing.php,search for is_deceased). Seems like quite a few people stumble on this and this should be fixed in core, IMO

Comment: I'm glad my comment helped, and thanks for posting your fix, which is surely better for all of us who are comfortable using phpMyAdmin.

I've filed an issue, here: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16681

Answer (score 1):

You might want to also account for contacts whose email is on hold, deceased or unsubscribed from the group.

If this still does not account for all the contacts, you should see if you can find a contact that should be in the recipient list but is not.

One way of debugging this might be to use the mysql query log and see the set of queries used to generate the recipient list

Comment: Thanks. I've found a few contacts that are in the mailing list group, but are not receiving the email.  They are NOT set to on hold, deceased or unsubscribed so something else must be stopping them from being added as a recipient.  

I'll take a look at the database/query and will post back here.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've taken a look at the mysql query log, and can't see anything out of the normal.   I have noticed that if I go to a contact that is not being included in the mailing list, and edit and save that contact it then gets properly added to the mailing list.   At this point I am going to go through all contacts and manually save them I think.

Comment: I've found further information.  It appears as though it is just contacts that have been imported from another CiviCRM installation that are not being added to the recipient list when sending a mailing.  This has me stumped as these contacts appear to have all valid fields in the database.

Comment: If i had to guess, there is some pattern among those included contacts that is responsible for them being kept out of the mailing. You might want to check that they are "Added" to the group instead of being in "Pending" status

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with imported contacts in my mailings. When I edited a contact and ticked, un-ticked the deceased and then saved the record, it was then included in the mailing.I will use the UPDATE command to set deceased to 0.

Comment: ah those zombies be trouble